# load RGB image and convert to CMYK

Tags: postscript

How can I load an image from source file in postscript and convert it into cmyk?

Shell I use DCTDecode?

I have no idea how to achieve this. I found some example that prints rgb image but that is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this ? In order to manage it you would have to know about how the image operator works in PostScript, and then examine the PostScript program in some detail to work out what you need to do to extract the image samples. Then you would need to convert those to CMYK.

If you wanted to inject that back into the original file, you would need some more PostScript programming skills to figure out how to do it. Its possible, but its not trivial, perhaps if you could explain your goal a better approach might be possible.

One approach is to convert the PostScript file to PDF, then use Adobe Acrobat Professional to 'touch up' the image, which can open the image in an image-editing application(eg Photoshop) where you could do the conversion.

The question can't really be answered as is.

Comment: I'm currently working on a project that tries to transfer data(text, image) from user trough web (using canvas) to a printing service in PS format. Every document has to be converted into CMYK color space before print, otherwise the result will be poor. I found a lot of stuff (books, manuals) about PS but I cant understand them without example. Summing all: I need _generate_ PS files and its color space must be CMYK.

Comment: I would be very grateful for a forum(link) specified to PS for people from beginners to experts, because as I see in SO this topic is not so popular.

Comment: @2astalavista You could try the newsgroup comp.lang.postscript through [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.lang.postscript). There is a searchable archive going back to 1985.

Comment: Your starting point should be to generate the CMYK image in the PostScript file rather than trying to convert it after inclusion. Are you generating the PostScript yourself, or using an application ? If you are generating the PostScript yourself then simply set the colour space to CMYK and make sure you generate 4-component samples. This should be trivial if you are already generating RGB images.

Comment: If you are going to generate PostScript files you *must* understand the language (PostScript is a programming language). You need to be familiar with the Red Book (PostScript Language Reference Manual) and you should probably read the Blue Book (PostScript language tutorials and cookbook) and Green Book (program design) as well.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions!